# Neglect last record in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

How to neglect last record and select other records and assign to a variable in mongodb.
I have tried to get last record for user id -862..How to get other records other than the last one.

```
db.product_logs.find({"user_id" :"862"}).sort({"_id":-1}).limit(1)
```

Comment: you can use `.skip(1)` function along with `.sort({"_id":-1})`, skip will fetch records from second position when you pass 1, and limit() is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

you have to skip the last one instead of limit

```
db.product_logs.find({"user_id" :"862"}).sort({"_id":-1}).skip(1)
```

Comment: you missed skip() function.